# MAGENTO 2 Email footer.html links not working

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, footer-links

In my module http://magento2/app/design/frontend/company/module/Magento_Email/email/footer.html

there is this line:

```
<td>
  <p><a href="/about-us">{{trans "About Uss"}}</a></p>
  <p><a href="/contact">{{trans "Customer Servicee"}}</a></p>
</td>
```

However when I get the Email the link doesn't work.

When I copy the link this is what it looks like:

> x-webdoc://EF91B121-13BE-4DCE-814F-ED522ADF4BB5/about-us
>
> x-webdoc://EF91B121-13BE-4DCE-814F-ED522ADF4BB5/contact

Can you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

```
<p><a href="{{store direct_url='contact'}}">{{trans "Customer Servicee"}}</a></p>
```

Comment: Is this working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!

Apparently it needs to have the full path including the domain just as /contact it does not work and does not know the root public_html so it has to be hard coded like this:

```
<td>
  <p><a href="http://magento2/about-us">{{trans "About Uss"}}</a></p>
  <p><a href="http://magento2/contact">{{trans "Customer Servicee"}}</a></p>
</td>
```

I know that this might be a different question but it's related. Now does anyone know how get base url in this footer.html ??